# An item with the same key has already been added in Properties?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I upgrade my computer and upgraded to VS2013 (So I believe) and now I get "An item with the same key already has been added. No one else in the same project gets this error and I haven't changed the base code. Whenever I right-click on projects and "General" I get this dialog box. Not sure if there something in my registry or somewhere that I need to delete. I still have VS2008 and VS2010 installed as well. Any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Could this be relevant?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648060/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added

Comment: Sorry-When I attempt to right-click on "properties" or "General", I get "An item with the same key has already been added. I haven't changed any of the other setting

Comment: The link seems to reference code issues. This is not the case for me. Others are running the exact same code without this error. It seems like there may be some conflict with my VS2013 and either another instance or something else