# An Exception is raised only when breaking at a breakpoint

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

There is a similar question. The problem that I'm having is that this defied the debugging system. The debugger created the problem.

So I have the following class:

```
public class Cache<TKey, TData> : Dictionary<TKey, TData>
{
    public TData Get(TKey key, Func<TData> generate)
    {
        if (TryGetValue(key, out TData data))
        {
            return data;
        }
        try
        {
            Add(key, data = generate());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Now If I put a *breakpoint* in any of my `generate` functions I get an exception. **`ArgumentException` An item with the same key has already been added.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An item with the same key has already been added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648060/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added)

Comment: Your method is not thread safe. Possibly it is called twice at roughly the same time from two threads. Without the breakpoint you usually get lucky, and the first call finishes before the second starts. With the breakpoint,  the second call will always fail. (And as you said below, the debugger may actually call your get method itself too). Consider using a lock.

Comment: It is already resolved, the OP did not realize that his debug watch expressions caused this code to run.

Comment: What I didn't realize was that even without a watch the debug system collects all the class data. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
Add(key, data = generate());
```

with

```
this[key] = data = generate();
```

When you assign via `this[index]`, it will either add or update, depending on whether the key already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that since I use this `Get` method in Properties. When the app *break*'s the debugger gets all the properties of my class hence all my caches get filled after having checked for the key but before adding it. This was very hard to debug but at least I figured it out. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid this.

Comment: Possibly by avoiding side-effects in getters?