# Azure function throws Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am facing one issue with Azure function. When I run a function it throws me with the below error

> Java HTTP trigger processed a request.
>    Function "GetPoolFunction" (ID: cb5d4ff4-f6c4-4986-96ba-8590e59b7423) invoked by Java Worker
>    Executed 'Functions.GetPoolFunction' (Succeeded, Id=5cda0f15-36e4-4f1d-9d4e-3e4a9fb296f3)
>    An unhandled host error has occurred.
>    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core: An item with the same key has already been added.

Please help if any one has gone throw this issue.

Thanks and Regards,
Balki

Comment: Seems not an Azure function specific problem, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648060/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added), if it doesn't help, you could provide your code snippet.

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thanks but this does solve my problem. I am writing the function app in javaBelow is the snippet of the code

Comment: Hi Jerry, I am writing the code in java for the function app @FunctionName("GetPoolFunction")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(@HttpTrigger(name = "reqpoolsfunction", methods = {
            HttpMethod.GET }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS,webHookType=WebHookType.NONE,route="v1/getpool") HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
               final ExecutionContext context) So when this code was compiled with the help of maven it generate the function.json file

Comment: {
  "scriptFile" : "..\\premiumandpenaltyfunction-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "net.scorpiogroup.pool.pnp.functions.getpoolfunction.GetPoolFunction.run",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "httpTrigger",
    "name" : "reqpoolsfunction",
    "direction" : "in",
    "route" : "v1/getpool",
    "authLevel" : "anonymous",
    "methods" : [ "GET" ]
  },  {
    "type" : "http",
    "name" : "$return",
    "direction" : "out"
  } ]
}

Comment: So in my application I have three functions and evity the out direction name is same that what i guess its happening wrong I change the out parameter by no luck.

Comment: You code seems outdated as `webHookType` has been abandoned in new function jave worker. Could you try to work with latest [cli](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#installing), create new function app and put your code there? If it doesn't work, could you put three function method signatures(like the one above) in your question?

Comment: Thanks Jerry I am able to solve the issue by clearing the cahe using command. nuget.exe local --clear and after this command the code works and also done a dotnet restore to restore the extensions.